# Controlling playback in scenekit Animations

Tags: collada, scenekit

Hi Is there a way I can control the playback of an animation imported from a collada file (DAE).

For example I have a few animations in one collada file such as walk,run,idle and I want to control the playback head to skip into the individual animations?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do the same thing. I have a collada file with many animations in it, and I'm trying to figure out how to split them out in a way that is useful. Did you figure this out? The sample code linked below loads a separate file for each animation... doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

the [Scene Kit Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SceneKitAnimations/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code shows how to retrieve and play individual animations.